# While creating object of a class, how to pass string array object as an argument into constructor of the class

Tags: angular, typescript

While creating object of a class, how to pass string array object as an argument into constructor of the class.

```
export class ManagerComponent {
    private selectedFilters: SelectedFilters;
    public ngOnInit() {
        this.selectedFilters = new SelectedFilters(new String[]);
    }
}

export class SelectedFilters {
    constructor(public related: String[]) { }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To initialize an array just use `[ values ]`:

```
this.selectedFilters = new SelectedFilters(['Test']); // Array with a string
this.selectedFilters = new SelectedFilters([]); // Empty array
```